# H1 tag not inheriting CSS styles

Tags: html, css

My `h1` tag is not getting styles of my css.

```
<h1 class=123>ExampleText</h1>
```

I targetted this is and it still doesn't allow me to change the properties of the `h1` tag.

Comment: Please share some example code or something so we can reproduce the issue and get more detail about the problem.

Comment: So i have made a h1 tag, and gave it a class. The code above is what it looks like I then have used CSS like this 
    .123 {
    text-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    } 

And its not working on my code.

Comment: Please see [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: @SArnab — Not true. Quotes are only required if the value contains certain characters, and that example contains none of them.

Comment: @Quentin wow, you're right, just checked it in the HTML5 spec. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: The css selector should be  .\31 23 {   }

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a invalid CSS class  because a CSS class selector can't start with a number

From [w3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

> In CSS, identifiers  (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters +00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

So nothing related to missing quotes, as others mentioned. Because as [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) explained very well in a comment:

> Quotes are only required if the value contains certain characters, and
>   that example contains none of them

See this example:

```css
h1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  float: left
}
.123 {
  background: red
}
.n123 {
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<h1 class=123></h1>
<h1 class=n123></h1>
<h1 class="123"></h1>
<h1 class="n123"></h1>
```

Comment: That isn't exactly true. A class can start with a number, a CSS class selector cannot

Comment: you right, I'm going to fix it :) @Quentin thanks for that I wasn't thinking that out of the box :) Fixed